# Tauri app crashes when running a command that writes to a file

Tags: rust, tauri

I created a tauri command that creates a file and writes data to it, however, every time I invoke the command from the frontend, the app crashes and restarts.

the command looks something like this

```rs
#[tauri::command]
pub fn create_file(name: String, data: String) {
    if let Ok(mut out) = File::create(format!("./src/ext/{}", name)) {
        out.write(data.as_bytes());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: ummm, shot in the dark, but typical development with tauri includes watching for source code changes and rebuilding automatically... and you're writing to the `./src` directory... it could be your tooling is doing exactly what its designed to do, just a hunch though

Comment: @kmdreko does it watch for changes in ./src only or on src-tauri as well?

Comment: Not sure, its been a while since I used tauri. I was simply posing the idea of using a different directory to see if it solves your problem

Comment: Yup. saving it in a different location solves this issue. For some reason, I forgot about tauri watching for changes in src directory. Thanks a lot!